# PHP multiplication table not showing

Tags: php, echo

In PHP, my printTable function isn't printing my table, instead prints nothing!

My printTable function supposed to print out multiplication table, instead it wont work as expected.

```
function printTable($min, $max) {
    $res = '';

    $res .= "<table border='1'>";

    $res .= '<tr><th>x</th>';

    for($num = $min; $num <= $max; $num = $num + 1) 
        $res .= "<th>$num</th>";

    $res .= '</tr>';

    for($num = $min; $num <= $max; $num = $num + 1) {
        echo "<tr>";

        for($multBy = $min; $multBy <= $max; $multBy = $multBy + 1) {
            if($multBy==$min) {
                $res .= "<th>$multBy</th>";
            }

            $total = $num * $multBy;
            $res .= "<td>$total</td>";
        }

        $res .= "</tr>";
    }

    $res .= "</table>";
}

echo printTable(1, 12);
```

EDIT
the problem is now fixed

Comment: You need to return $res at the end of your printTable() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value of `$res` before you can use it. Add this at the bottom of the `printTable` function:

```
return $res;
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: what does return do?

Comment: `return` simply dumps a value out from the function that you can use when you call the function. For example, if a function called `sum` returns the sum of the first two arguments, then you can use `echo sum(5, 9);` to output your result. You can even store the result in a variable.

Comment: im going to try that in my code and test if it works

Comment: If it did, then click on the green check mark to accept this answer. It will benefit the both of us.